# Converting 3 star rating to 5 star

Tags: math, rating-system

I have some data in which the ratings are from 1 to 5.

But another department who gave us data has given it in 1 to 3.

Is there a way to convert those 1 to 3 rating and spread it on 1 to 5? Or a mathematical way to do this?

[image: Data loos something like this - they just have 1 - 5 (6 is N/A)]

Comment: The formula is `R_5 = (R_3 / 3) * 5 '.

Comment: How do you want to map them? if just 1->, 2->3 3->5 then its just 2x-1. If you want a different spread of outputs then you will need to be more specific on how you want them to map.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca I'm not sure I'd expect a 1* rating to be mapped to a 1.6667 star rating...

Comment: It is a trivial proportion: 1.6667 for a scale 1 .. 5 is the right answer. By the same formula: 1,5 in 1 ..  3 is 2,5 in 1 .. 5.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca: My point is that you have mapped 1-3 to 1.667-5 which is not the same as being mapped to 1-5. Its obviously up to the OP what they want but to me at least that doesnt' seem to fit the requirements. I'd agree with your formula if it was a 0-3 being converted to 0-5 but that isn't the case here from what the OP said.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca you solution works fine for me as I can round them off a little